# meta_query for keys that aren't yet set

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, meta-query

I'm trying to query for a custom post type for a gallery system. I have a checkbox to set a gallery as a "featured" gallery (set up through More Fields plugin) - if this is checked then the meta value becomes 1 and then if unchecked it becomes 0. All good. However if the box has never been checked then the meta key is never created, meaning I can't query for NOT LIKE 1 because it doesn't exist.

The query I want is to pull out 4 galleries that aren't marked as '1' in this meta value, but also those that don't have this value at all. Is there a way to always give newly added posts a default value for this meta key (ie always make them 0 by default if the box is left unchecked) or is there a way to query for the key not yet being set?

My current query is:

```
$args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'gallery',
                        'showposts' => 4,
                        'meta_key' => 'gal-ID',
                        'order_by' => 'meta_value',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'meta_query' => array( array(
                                            'key' => 'main-gal',
                                            'value' => false,
                                        ) ),
                        ) );
```

And I've tried various attempts with 'compare' => 'NOT LIKE', '!=' etc etc.

Any ideas? This ticket seems to imply it's something that ought to be sorted out:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18158

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

That massive function was a bit scary, I got this working like so - with two arguments (that exclude the features)

```
$args = array(

    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
            array( // new and edited posts
                'key' => 'Set as Featured Post',
                'compare' => '!=',
                'value' => 1
            ),

            array( // get old posts w/out custom field
                'key' => 'Set as Featured Post',
                'value' => '1',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            ) 
        ),
    'posts_per_page' => 30

);
```

Comment: My first array is overriding my second with this solution. It seems maybe you can't double query the same field?

Answer (score 3):

As per [Custom Field Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) in Codex, special `NOT EXISTS` compare is available since WP version 3.5

Technically it produces something like following SQL query in posts requests:

```
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'wrong',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
) );
```

```sql
SELECT *,wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'wrong')
WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND (wp_postmeta.post_id IS NULL)
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 5
```

It works by joining meta table on provided key and only selecting records where that hadn't resulted in meaningful data (`IS NULL`). So it works only for case when key doesn't exist at all and won't work for keys that exist with *falsy* values.

Comment: I'm intrigued by this `NOT EXISTS` compare.  As a work around for unset meta keys, I just save a 0 on the `save_post` hook if the meta key isn't set.  How does `NOT EXISTS` work? Will it sort the OP's query by `main-gal` and then fill in the 4 with the posts that don't have that meta?

Comment: @helgatheviking I've elaborated on mechanics in answer

Answer (score 2):

As the ticket pointed out, it's not supported.. until then you'll have to rely on a custom solution.

A few users have asked for this before, or at least asked how to do it over on the WordPress.org forums, so i wrote a function to do the job which i never kept hold of(pastebinned), fortunately i found the original topic where i provided the pastebin link(which shouldn't expire).

http://pastebin.com/kgLt1RrG

I wrote that 8 months ago and i've not tested it(since then), so let me know of any issues.

Hope that helps..

Comment: Cool, thanks for this - will test it out later this evening and let you know what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method, albeit not the cleanest:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'gallery',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'gal-ID',
    'order_by' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => 'main-gal',
    ) );
```

This will give you all your galleries sorted by the meta key. The next step is to figure out if the galleries with the value 1 come after or before the other posts. This way you can either:

- Process items until you've processed either 4 gallery items, or reached a post with a meta value of 1
- Skip over the posts with a meta value 1 then start processing when you reach the first non-1 value

Other methods not requiring a custom SQL statement:

- Doing a query to find the galleries you dont want, using it to fill an array of post IDs, then doing a second query, passing that array in as posts to exclude
- Using a taxonomy instead of custom fields ( solves this quite nicely and puts a lot of other nice improvements in free of charge so its saving you time too )